# Storing an array of favorites in nativescript application-settings

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I see that `tns-core-modules/application-settings` has the ability to store data on the device.  I have an application where I would like to store a user's favorites to the device.

Assuming that I am storing a list of favorite songs, I could use `setString` and `getString`, but I am not sure how that can be done programmatically to get all songs.  Is there another option or way to implement this that I am missing, where a dict can be accessed with the `songs` as a key, and all `songs` can be loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify` along with `setString` / `JSON.parse` along with `getString`.

```
// Set favorite songs 
appSettings.setString("favorites", JSON.stringify(songs));

// Get favorite songs
const songs = JSON.parse(appSettings.getString("favorites", "{}"));
```

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how to track changes to data set using this approach?  Using the same example as the question, assume I have a page that displays these favorites and favorites can also be updated from other pages.  I would like all pages to be in sync with what has/hasn't been favorited.

Comment: Since you are using Angular, create a service that will handle reading / writing favorites to application settings. Keep an BehaviorSubject that always own the latest favorites data which each of your pages will subscribe to. When a page requests for updating favorites, let it go through this service, update application settings & the bahavior subject automatically all of it's subscribers will be notified.